# Does onBackPressed() stop the app?

Tags: android, android-activity, ads, android-lifecycle, onbackpressed

Sorry for the question, that is not purely technique.

we published our app on Play Store. We used AdBuddiz advirtised provider.

Google has suspended our app, because of violating the following Ad Policy:

> Interstitial ads may only be displayed inside of the app they came
>   with. A prominent and accessible target must be made available to
>   users in any interstitial ad so they may dismiss the ad without
>   penalty or inadvertent click-through.

What we did in our app is to show the ad when the user is in the main Activity, and press back. The code we use is the following:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   AdBuddiz.showAd(this);
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

So the question is: Did our app violate the policy? The user presses is inside the app when the ad is shown. However, the android Activity lifecycle do not guarantee that after the backPress the app is not running, since it should just call `finish()`.

We are considering to compile the Google Appel form, for recovering our app. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is a bad UX decision to show an Ad wenn the user wants to close the app.

Beside that there is a (sadly) common way to make a double back press behave as a real exit. A well known app like 9gag uses that to prevent accidental leaves.

You could to the same like this:

```
private boolean mAdShownOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mAdshownOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mAdShownOnce = true;
        AdBuddiz.showAd(this);
        mLastBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Consider that the user might "learn" that he has to press three times to close the app (I think he can dismiss the ad by pressing back, right?!).

Answer (score 0):

`super.onBackPressed()` will in many case close the app. You should delete this line and provide your own logic to ensure it does not.

Comment: You must call super at some point or your app will never terminate!

Comment: True. You may instead call finish() on every one of your activities. It will also kill the app.

Not to mention that Android specifications encourage NOT terminating the app yourself, but making the user leave with the HOME button and letting system do all the terminating when required.

Answer (score 0):

`super.onBackPressed();` will let the OS know that app is not running anymore. And your add will still be there. You should just display the add on back press and on the close event finish this activity.